# How to create Tinder like drag initiated animation, inside a tableviewcell (swift)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

Currently I understand how to replicate the tinder effect on a normal `viewcontroller`, but how would I implement this inside each individual `uitableviewcells`?

The idea is to have a image inside each cell and when it is dragged, it moves horizontally within the cell, according to the motion.

I tried to assign a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the image within the cell but it is not responding.

If someone could outline the general direction of how this can be done I would be very grateful!

Comment: did you enabled user interaction of UIImageview?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `UIContainerView` which basically has your image, name etc. stored.
I've done it this way, took a little bit, but works amazingly.

The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is then attached to the container